# Java jSF NamedQuery using an Int

Tags: java, jsf, hql, named-query

I am making a search query for a integer. This is the NamedQuery in the class Factuur:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "getFactuurs", query = "SELECT f FROM Factuur f WHERE "
+ "f.periode LIKE :periode AND "
+ "f.carTracker.kenteken LIKE :carTrackerKenteken")
```

})

So the 'periode' is an Integer in the class Factuur, I have tried to do it this way:

```
    + "f.periode = :periode AND "
```

I don't get an Exception, I just get nothing from the database, while there should be...

Comment: Are you sure that there is at least one record in the db which matches the values of `periode` and the `carTrackerKenteken` you pass in?

Answer (score 0):

Section 4.6.9 of the JPA specification states that the LIKE operator can only be applied to expressions of type string:

> The syntax for the use of the comparison operator [NOT] LIKE in a conditional expression is as follows:
>
> ```
>       string_expression [NOT] LIKE pattern_value [ESCAPE escape_character]
> ```
>
> The string_expression must have a string value.

There does not seem to be a function to convert an integer to a string. If you are querying for a range you should probably calculate the lower and upper values in your application and query with a BETWEEN expression. If you need to query with arbitrary LIKE expressions then your field should probably be of type string.